# Is there any library available for finding US city's county name?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find county name using United City's city name or using zipcode.

I have tried to find the python library but i didn't get.

I want couty name using pass city name or zipcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [uszipcode on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/uszipcode/) would be your best bet! It includes county information off of zip codes. (Note: this is a database-driven library, and may affect performance or be deprecated in the future, so be careful using it!)

There's also a great [previous question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251762/lightweight-python-library-to-query-city-state-name-by-zip-code) with some code examples!